# Не обновляется pip в виртуальной среде

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pip

Создал виртуальную среду в python. Пробую обновить pip командой

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Но pip не обновляется, отвечает что pip уже установлен. Хотя в виртуальной среде  установлен pip 9 версии. И он не хочет обновится до последней версии. Из-за чего это может быть?
Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6

Comment: Вы не забыли активировать виртуальную среду перед выполнением этой команды?

Comment: Или даже так: а как именно вы проверили, что в виртуальной среде установлен pip именно 9 версии?

Comment: активировал виртуальную среду и по команде pip -V

Comment: https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/01_intro/pip.html#pip-pip3